# PHPMailer response

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm using phpmailer to send email with the function:

```
function send_email($address, $message){
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "name@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "password";
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->From = "name@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "Name";
$mail->addAddress($address, "Cust. name");

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Nueva clave";
$mail->Body = "<i>".$message."</i>";
$mail->AltBody = "This is yout password.";

if($mail->send())
{
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
}
```

in my php file I set the response header this way:
    `header('Content-Type: application/json');` after the process that needs to be made I handle email this way:

```
 if(send_email('customer@gmail.com', $message))
        {
            array_push($response, 'email sent');
            array_push($response, $new_password);
            echo json_encode(array('errors'=>$errors, 'response' => $response));
        }
        else
        {
            array_push($errors, 'email not send');
            array_push($errors, $new_password);
            echo json_encode(array('errors'=>$errors, 'response' => $response));
        }
```

normally I expected a response from the server like: Object[errors[],response[]] just as several times I have done this, however instead I'm receiving this as an answer [image: JSON RESPONSE]

why I'm getting this response, do I need any other configuration that was not set.
Thanks

Comment: In you code context this answer good. because 'email sent' and new password generated...

Comment: If you email don't sending, check you email box in from(or return path) for get read returned emails from over servers.

Comment: but how can I read that answer for example in the $.ajax({
                                                       success: function(response){
}
})

Comment: like this `$.ajax({ success: function(response){ response.response[0] // it's message; response.response[1] //this password }});` you can rename response in data for example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are including debug output in your response, which is not valid JSON. Just do this to turn it off:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
```

Comment: Sorry but why json is not valid?

Comment: @Naumov - the PHPMailer debug output (all that output above the "desired output" label) is just not in JSON format, but was being sent to something that's expecting JSON, so it was breaking.